# How to remove black areas of transparent image in reflection

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to render png emitted clouds but have no idea how to remove the black areas of png's reflection as shown below

[image]

[image]

Here's the node setup

[image]

Comment: maybe check the Properties panel > Render > Light Paths > Transparency values?

Answer (score 1):

I turned off its glossiness in the ray visibility menu under object tab

[image]

[image]

Could be the only way of solving the black background of the png as of the moment.